# Merge Elements Of int array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, merge, element

I've been looking around on MSDN and Stack overflow for a while now, but i can't seem to find anything, i want to merge elements of an int array. I've looked at string.join but can't seem to find an equivalent for int

```
int[] myArray = new int[] {1,4};
int myArray[0] + myArray[1] would equal 14, Note that i want to merge them together
not mathematically add them.
```

The whole program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Exercise2
{

/** Create a reference type called Person.  Populate the Person class with the following properties to store the following information:
First name
Last name
Email address
Date of birth **/ 

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string DOB = tbDOB.Text;
        DOB.Replace("\\"," ");
        int[] iDOB = DOB.Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
        int day = 

    }


}
```

}

Would it be better to change it to a char array?

Comment: Just wondering what i can do to increase the quality of the question? I see it's got 2 down votes pretty quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.Concat` and then parse the result to integer:

```
int result = int.Parse(string.Concat(myArray));
```

Also strings are immutable, you need to assign `DOB` back, and you need to replace non-digit chars with `string.Empty` not with a *white-space* otherwise you will get a `FormatException`.

```
DOB = DOB.Replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: Would this require me to have myArray as a string to start with?

Comment: no you said myArray is an array of integer and this code will work if it is.